# php - how to insert element in database in loop

Tags: php, mysql

I need help regarding this code i wrote. Can anybody help me find the error..

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $a = $row['ID'];
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td><td>" . $row['attended'] . "</td><td>".$row['missed']."</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='present[]' value='$a'>Present</td></tr>";
    }       

}
if(!empty($_POST['present'])) 
{
     foreach($_POST['present'] as $present) 
     {

         $query = "UPDATE dwdm SET attended = attended + 1 WHERE ID = '{$present}'";
         $run_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
     }
}
```

All I am trying to do is store the values of the checkbox in an array (store the corresponding value of the checkbox the user ticks on).
and then increment a field in the database WHERE id = corresponding enroll no. the user checks. if more than one increment both. but when 
1) I checks the box, it do not works on the first time and the second time it increments.
2) and same thing happens when I switch the checkboxes. It increments the other row which was not checked. Note- this occurs on the first try only.

[image: refer the image]

[image: image of the db]

Comment: *"how to insert element"* - Yet your query is "UPDATE".

Comment: *"store the corresponding value of the checkbox the user ticks on"* - where's the form for it?

Comment: *"Note- this occurs on the first try only."* - check for errors then with `mysqli_error($conn)` on the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're querying the database and displaying the table before you do the updates, so you're seeing the previous data. Switch the order.

```
if(!empty($_POST['present'])) 
{
     foreach($_POST['present'] as $present) 
     {
         $query = "UPDATE dwdm SET attended = attended + 1 WHERE ID = '{$present}'";
         $run_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
     }
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM dwdm");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $a = $row['ID'];
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td><td>" . $row['attended'] . "</td><td>".$row['missed']."</td><td><input type='checkbox' name='present[]' value='$a'>Present</td></tr>";
    }       
}
```